# How to fit a BeQuite Silent Wing 3 FAN to my HP Proliant N40L?

Tags: motherboard, fan

I want to replace the case FAN of my HP Proliant N40L Server with [a Silent Wings 3 120mm PWM](https://www.bequiet.com/en/casefans/722), however I can not fit it on the motherboard socket for the fan.

Unfortunately I could not find any manual of the mainboard online but [this](https://www.ebay.de/p/1323245232) is the exact one I have.

The fan socket has 4 Pins on the mainbaord but there is a plastic "wall" behind those 4 Pins so the Silent Wings 3 won't fit.

The white plug is the original one from the Case FAN and the black one is the Silent Wings3.

[image]

So I am wondering if I can just remove the two black plastic things from the Silent Wings 3 so I can plug it in? I really don't want to solder the white one to my Silent Wings.

I also did not find any other silent fan which such kind of plug...

DrMoishe Pippik gave me a lot to consider so I updated the question:

[This](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Delta-Electronics/AFB1212VH?qs=%2FW4LtXOBxKur%252BRAJsGU4Gg%3D%3D) is the fan I want to replace because it is too noisy for me.
It looks like the Silent Wings3 does not move as much air as the original one. 85.8 to 104 apparently but I am also not sure if the difference matters? This Fan is only used for cooling the 4 HDDs.
I have no idea if it fits regarding the pin outs. I am also happy to get another FAN if this does not fit, I just need it to be under 20db(A). Tbh, I feel like the Silent Wings 3 is not the perfect fit.

Comment: 1. Does it move enough air to cool the server? 2. Do you have the pin-outs for original fan (you'd need to look up that for the *fan* you're replacing) and for the new one? Finding info for the *fan* should be easier than for the PCB. 3. Are the fans electrically compatible (voltage, current, control lines...)?

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I did my best to update the question. I am absolutely not sure about the pin-out tbh.

Comment: The new, quiet fan spec: Air Flow @ 100% PWM / 12V 50.5 CFM. The old fan spec: 104 CFM. According to manufacturer's spec,s for which *you* provided links, you would get a bit less than one-half the airflow at full throttle. So, yes, it might be more quiet, but the *smell* of burning components might be more objectionable.

Comment: ok, so there are no fans apparently with my specs. But I still feel like 44 db(A) is quite noisy...

Comment: So this will have enough airflow and is silent https://noctua.at/de/nf-a12x25-pwm/specification.
But the plug will still not fit, so can I "make" it fit?